# Predict for sm.regression

Tags: r, regression

I want to fit a nonparametric regression to some data using `sm.regression` from the `sm` package and predict values at given points.

```r
# Load package
library(sm)

# Create dummy data
df <- data.frame(x = 1:10, y = (1:10)^2)

# Fit nonparametric regression
res <- with(df, sm.regression(x = x, y = y, eval.points = 3.25))
```

[image]

```r
# Examine result
with(res, cbind(eval.points, estimate))
#>      eval.points estimate
#> [1,]        3.25 11.18666
```

<sup>Created on 2019-09-06 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

This gives an estimated value at `x = 3.25`, for example.

Now, say I want to use this regression later on to predict another value. With methods such as `loess`, I could simply use the fitted model with new data in `predict()`. There doesn't seem to be a corresponding `predict` function for an `sm.regression`, however.

My question is, **do I have to refit the model every time I want to make a prediction, like above, when making predictions with an `sm.regression`?**